# Automating a Browser's Open File Dialog

Tags: javascript, web, browser

## Example

Take https://hexed.it/ for instance. Say you want to analyse many files. Steps I would take:

1. Execute javascript:

   `document.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].click()`
2. Set the 'File Name' to the path of one of your files and `click` the open button.
3. After Hex has loaded in, perform some javascript on it.

---

## Problem

The problem is that Javascript, on most browsers, can not automate file dialogs, for security reasons.

## Possible resolutions

1. A plugin could give JS access to USER32.DLL. This would enable access to the user interface.
2. A non-standard 'insecure' browser?

Does anyone know a quick and easy solution?

Comment: A short answer: yes.

Comment: I've edited my question --> "And if so, where can I find it?"

Comment: That question is off-topic for SO, "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: This might be on-topic for [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you explain in detail what kind of filesystem access you need and how it should work. It might also be answerable here, if you explain what you're actually trying to do (e.g., "I need a script to [read a file from]/[write a file to] the user's file system [to do thing X] without having the user pick it out; how do I do this in browser JavaScript? I am willing to use extensions or a non-standard browser environment; if they exist, what does their API look like for file access?").

Comment: @Apsillers Thank you both for giving the heads up, I've edited the question but I assume it should still be moved to Software Recs?

Comment: It must be me but I can't extract the least sense from this question. If it's about automating uploads to a third-party site that doesn't have an API I'm pretty sure you don't need to write a browser: you have many existing tools to automate browser interaction, from testing frameworks like Selenium to browser extensions, or you could even write an extension yourself, or a command line script that does not involve a browser at all (remote site won't note the difference). What DLLs have to do with it is a mystery to me.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Some of us (e.g. me) don't know about / have never used frameworks such as Selenium and thus don't know the extent of features such languages / frameworks / browser plugins have. Using User32.dll is what I would do, as it's what I know how to use. If you have more knowledge, feel free to enlighten me regarding the better approaches.

Comment: What I mean is that I can't really understand what you want to do, since the DLL looks like the intended solution, not the ultimate goal. (I suppose "call a DLL" means writing client-side JavaScript code on top of a library that provides binding with C-style dynamic libraries so you can use methods from the Win32 API but that's beyond my area of expertise so I haven't even asked.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález You are absolutely correct. I've re-read my post and I see that it's very open to interpratation as to what I'm asking for... Specifically I wanted to know how to automate an open file dialog,

Comment: Is that's really all? As in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/mecuqiniwu/edit?html,js,output)? (You may need to disable the pop-up blocker.)

Comment: Yes that is all I wanted to do.

Comment: Well, in Firefox you have [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) to run custom JavaScript on sites. I guess everybody uses Chrome nowadays but I suppose it has similar extensions.

Comment: ^ Greasemonkey simply enables FF to do what is called _userscripts_. It's actually a concept that comes from Opera, however userscripts are cross-browser as long as you can enable support - in Firefox that is done though Greased key, while Chrome has Tampermonkey. Both do the same and userscripts work with both. Opera supports them natively, I believe but I'm not sure about IE and Edge.